# NHibernate Invalid Cast - Property type mismatches when using queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

After several hours of reading through several similar issues, I am still unable to find the issue I'm having. The exception is occurring in the query which is as follows:

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.AddAssembly(typeof(TestCase).Assembly);
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    ICriteria targetObjects = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TestCase));
    IList<TestCase> itemList = targetObjects.List<TestCase>(); //Exception raised here
```

The exception is "Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of TestProject.TestCase"

With an InnerException of {"Specified cast is not valid."}

The class for this is as follows:

```
    public virtual Guid Id               { get; set; }
    public virtual ushort Priority       { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description    { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Project { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name           { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Created     { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Updated     { get; set; }
```

And the mapping file is

```
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                       assembly="TestProject"
                       namespace="TestProject">
      <class name="TestCase"
             table="test_table"
             lazy="true">
        <id name="Id" column="ID" type="Guid">
          <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="Priority" column="Priority"
                  type="int" />
        <property name="Description" column="Description"
                  type="string" />
        <property name="Name" column="Name"
                  type="string" />
        <property name="Created" column="Created"
                  type="DateTime" />
        <property name="Updated" column="Updated"
                  type="DateTime" />
        <list table="ProjTable" name="Project">
          <key column="TestID" />
          <list-index column="ProjIndex" />
          <element column="ProjCol" />
        </list>
     </class>
    </nhibernate-mapping>
```

I'm not overly familiar with SQL but it has helped me in debugging this project in the past, so I'll post what's generated:

```
    NHibernate: SELECT this_.ID as ID0_0_, this_.Priority as Priority0_0_,
    this_.Description as Descript4_0_0_, this_.Test_Name as Test5_0_0_, 
    this_.Created as Created0_0_, this_.Updated as Updated0_0_ FROM test_table this_
```

I have been able to load values into the table using this mapping, but I have been unable to use queries of any kind without finding this error. I've looked myself and I cannot seem to find the cause.

What I've tried:
-Different queries
-Changing DateTime? to DateTime (read this as a possible solution somewhere)
-Played around with the structure of the line where the exception occurred

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this and similar basic issues for several hours over the past few days.

Comment: Is `TestProject.TestCase` the actual name, or did you rename them for the question?  I'm asking because it feels like something isn't coming across in the question quite right.  You have `namespace="TestProject.TestCase"`, as well as `class name="TestProject.TestCase"`, and also the error stating something about a property named `TestProject.TestCase`.  So all three - namespace, class, and property are named exactly the same.  Either that's your issue, or there are errors in the way you've stated the problem.

Comment: That's how they're named; based on other information I gathered during the setup, that's what seemed correct to do. I'll have a look at whether or not that fixes things, however. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't seem to fix anything, but I did clean up the XML a bit and it does still work for inserting data into the table. I have updated the XML in the main post accordingly.

I did a few other tests on some discrepancies I noticed elsewhere as I was looking through the code again, but they didn't accomplish anything either. I'll keep working on it. Again, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, and I'm not sure why I didn't think about it before.

By removing the types from the .hbm.xml, it let the queries go through unhindered. After some more testing, I have concluded that the Priority column was not happy about being an int OR a uint. I assume this is an issue with how MySQL stores the integers in comparison to how C# does, most likely because I have them flagged as unsigned on the database side. As a fix, I have simply removed that type from the XML.